# How to see all sessions in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session

Tried to delete all sessions, based on an answer from SO, but it didn't work.

How to see all sessions in Rails 3?

Rails 3.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in any view: `<%= debug session %>` and to clean all session simply use Firebug or Web Inspector and delete all cookies.